# AWS Cloud9 IDE. How do I jump to matching brackets?

Tags: editor

AWS Cloud9 IDE.
How do I jump to matching brackets?
Like the "%" key in vi.
What is this editor called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a MAC I used

1. Control+P and it would jump between brackets
2. Command+Shift+| and it highlighted the complete code block and then i could just arrow up or down if i wanted the beginning or ending bracket

[image: Jump to Matching Brace]